# What adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is supposed to do?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I want to fit font size of label's text to labels's frame width or height

I tried the next but nothing changes (font size of text is the same as it was)

```
label.numberOfLines = 1 // I tried 0 and 1...
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 1
```

Storyboard:

[image]

Simulator:

[image]

Nothing changes, doesn't it?

**Update**

Seems this one resizes text only if text doesn't fit within container (text is too big). If text is smaller than container's width then it does nothing

So I need something else...

Comment: Do you care how many lines? Or do you want a single line, but always display the full content?

Comment: @K.Wu only one line

Answer (score 0):

Set the `minimumScaleFactor` property of the label to something smaller than 1.

```
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620544-minimumscalefactor)

> If the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property is set to true, use this property to specify the smallest multiplier for the current font size that yields an acceptable font size to use when displaying the label’s text. If you specify a value of 0 for this property, the current font size is used as the smallest font size.The default value of this property is 0.

Comment: these options has nothing to do with what I need